# Resolving a rational system of equations with too many unkowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

**A little bit of context.**

While working a larger proof (the proof is quite related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066012/finding-irrational-entries-such-that-the-determinant-will-never-be-zero) I asked), I stumbled upon the following problem.

**The question.**

> Can we find $x_1,\ldots,x_{24}\in\mathbb Q$ such that for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q$:
>
> $$ (x_1a+x_2b+x_3c+x_4d)(x_5a+x_6b+x_7c+x_8d)-(x_{9}a+x_{10}b+x_{11}c+x_{12}d)(x_{13}a+x_{14}b+x_{15}c+x_{16}d)-(x_{17}a+x_{18}b+x_{19}c+x_{20}d)(x_{21}a+x_{22}b+x_{23}c+x_{24}d)$$
> $$=7a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2\quad ?$$

**What I tried.**

I have tried to do a systematic resolution of the underlying system, but this is too massive to compute.

I have tried arbitrarily fixing some of the $x_i$ in order to simplify the system, but I always end up in one of the following cases:

- no solution,
- irrational solutions,
- complex solutions.

None of this cases is acceptable.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just remove all the terms $x_{17}$ through $x_{24}$.  They are redundant with the preceding eight.  Replace $x_9$ with $x_9+x_{17}$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Legendre $3$-square theorem the right hand side can never vanish unless all terms are zero.

However, no mather what the $x_i$ are, it is possible with three linear conditions on $(a,b,c,d)$ to force the left hand side to vanish, meaning the left hand side has infinitely many rational zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we find explicitly  these linear conditions on $(a,b,c,d,)$?

Comment: Vanish one factor per term in your left hand side.

Comment: This answer may not be completely correct. The argument based on the 3-square does not seem to distinguish between the forms $$7a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2\\ 5a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$$ and the latter one has the requisite identity given in my answer.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: my proof is in two steps. First, I show that the right hand side has no nontrivial zero (for which I used Legendre’s theorem). Second, I show that no matter what rational numbers the $x_i$ are, there is always a line $L \subset \mathbb{Q}^4$ such that the left hand side vanishes for every $(a,b,c,d) \in L$. This second step is absolutely independent of the quadratic form in the right hand side. On the other hand, $5a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=0$ has non-trivial rational solutions (multiples of $(1,2,3,0)$), thus the first step doesn’t work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a solution, though one may not have searched hard enough. For example, if your expression with the squares was,

$$D = 5a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$$

then I found,

$$\left(a+\frac b4+\frac c4+\frac d2\right)\big(4a-b+c-2d\big)-(-a + b + c + d)(a + b - c + d) -\left(-\frac {9b}4+\frac {9c}4-\frac{3d}2\right)\left(b+c+\frac{2d}3\right) =  5a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$$

In fact,

$$D = k\,a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$$

where $k=\frac{4n^2+1}{n}$ and other families are solvable, though I haven't come across one where $k=7$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it is not quite the same in my opinion : you have changed the sign in front of $b^2$ ($-\to +$), and I was interested in $7a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2$ since $7a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2=0$ has no rational solution ; but $5a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=0$ does...

Comment: @E.Joseph: I don't think that if $y_1 a^2+y_2 b^2+y_3 c^2+ y_4 d^2 = 0$ has no rational solutions, then it is a guarantee there are no 24 non-trivial rational $x_i$. If I have time, I may investigate this further.

Comment: If you find a form $y_1a^2+y_2b^2+y_3c^3+y_4d^4$ with no rational solution but such that there is a $24$ non-trivial rational solution, I would be really interested to hear about it!

Comment: @E.Joseph The form $D=ka^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$ with $k = (4n^2+1)/n$ has the 24 rational $x_i$. One need only check if there are $k$ such that $D=0$ is not solvable.

Comment: Yes exactly, I will think about this problem

Comment: I have tested it for $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and it does not work so far, $D=0$ is solvable for $n\leqslant 5$.